# Dual Boot Mistake, Tell Me Where I Likely Went Wrong

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

X-Post from Ubuntu Budgie Google+ Group..

Hello, could someone here help explain to me where I went wrong with my install? Basically I ran into an issue where I had Windows 10 configured on an SSD, and wanted to install Ubuntu Budgie on it as well for dual boot purposes. I eventually made my way to leaving two of the three Windows partitions, the Windows partition I got rid of was the Recovery partition which was then manually re-formatted for swap space, the fourth (and last) partition was formatted as ext4 for the Linux OS. After that was all installed and running the first red flag I noticed was that Windows did not appear in the boot list when restarting my machine and selecting boot options, however I dismissed it at first and continued on. After a Software Center (update all) run through I restarted and was was given a black screen with my login box. It still kept my username and showed my Computer name (Nemo) in the top left but after entering the password this screen would just regenerate itself and put me into an endless loop of signing in. I apologize for my crap terminology and my noobie question, as I'm trying to get started with Linux so that I can migrate my daily computing from macOS over to a Linux distro but that is proving to be quite difficult. Currently I'm in the process of reinstalling Windows fresh on a completely wiped SSD, and I'm considering using a different drive entirely to put Linux on to avoid any and all potential boot issues. (Side note, this is all taking place on a gaming PC, not a Mac)﻿

Comment: I see now Budgie will be an Offical flavor of Ubuntu. :) May be best to see details:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info What brand/model system? Are all installs in same boot mode, UEFI or BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't need to use two drives. Windows can have many Primary Partitions on a Single drive, Linux can only have 4 Primary partitions (PP). When you install Windows, you already consume a System Partition (PP1) and OS Partition (PP2). Now you should create a Large PP for common Data, accessible by Win and Lin both. It can be NTFS. Rest free space can be used to create two Logical Partitions. One for Lin /root (about 30 GB ext4) and another for Swap. These LPs to be created via Linux Live environment with Gparted. Now you can install Linux normally. Don't fail to put the Grub on MBR (sda/hda). Thats it. You won't need a /home, as you can mount the ntfs large common data partition to access and write data, in Win and Linux. 
If you have a Uefi machine, create a ext2 LP as /boot.

Hope this helps.